# Google Data studio dynamic data source connection

Tags: google-cloud-storage, looker-studio

Is there a way in **Google Data Studio** to dynamically add data source to a visualisation.

I'm able to create a line chart visualisation by making a **Google Cloud Storage** data connection.

But can i make that **data connection dynamic?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Cloud Storage Connector for Google Data Studio, the data should be always up to date although you might not see it due to the cache.

This is mentioned in [this document](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7511998#update-the-data), you can also check if you can alter the "Data Freshness" of the connector by following [these](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039) instructions.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: I want to generate graph with different csv files from cloud storage using data studio.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your comment, but if you want to have one graphic with data from 2 data sources, you would need to blend the data.

This is mentioned over [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420?hl=en). The only limit is that you can only blend 5 data sources.